# How to get row details without actually selecting the row of table in sapui5

Tags: jquery, sapui5

I have created a table in sapui5 in which data is populating from back end that is SAP Gateway. I have added a column in the table which contains a link. Each row has a link. If I click on that link, a popup box is opened. 
I want to pass the details of other columns of the same row whose link is selected in the popup box. And to get the details, I need the index of that row which I don't know.

How to achieve it ?

Comment: I tried but was able to get details of single column. I am not able to get the row-index.

Comment: Please add the sapui5 code you are attempting this now and it will be much easier to help

Comment: try to build an example using this page: http://jsbin.com/openui5-HTML-templates/77/edit

Comment: Are you using databinding to populate the data to your table? If so you could provide additional information to your Link using the CustomData attribute which can be accessed in a press event. You could store the whole row object in it and provide it to the popup. See the documentation for an example: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/CustomData.html

Comment: @TimGerlach isnt the rowObject=this.getContext().getObject() why not set the context to the popup instead

Comment: @Jasper_07: Sure! This sounds even better to me since passing the Context of the row object would allow access AND manipulations to the object in the model by the PopUp Dialog. You just have to make sure to pass the context of the whole row object rather than passing just the Link context.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `getSource()` and `getParent()` methods to walk up the control hierarchy like this:

```
function linkPressListener(oEv) {
   // get event source -> the link
   var link = oEv.getSource();
   // walk up the control hierarchy until you reach the table row (1st parent should be column, 2nd the row)
   var row = link.getParent().getParent();

   // get the rows index
   var index = row.getIndex();

   // get row context from the table
   var myTable = sap.ui.getCore().byId("myTablesID"); 
   myTable.getContextByIndex(index);

   // open your dialog using the rows context
   ...
}
```

Anyways depending on the hierarchy like this seems a little fragile to me, would love to see a more elegant example.

Comment: are you trying to get the index=sap.ui.getCore().byId("myTablesID").indexOfRow(this.getParent()) or the row context=this.getBindingContext() either way looks like your taking the scenic route

Comment: fyi this.getParent().getParent() === oTable not row

Answer (score 1):

I had more or less the same question but with RowRepeater control instead of Table. Have a look at the answer Jasper_07 provided at https://stackoverflow.com/a/21600210/3270057

This will give your access to the current binding context properties, or the whole object

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Get the model that you have bound to the table

`var model=that.getView().getModel("ModelName");
var path = evt.getSource().getParent().getBindingContextPath();
var data=model.getProperty(path);`

data should have the object that you have bound to the row and contains all the values you needed.